# Splitting a SQL Server Table Over Multiple Files With EF Core 5

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I appreciate your help in this matter.

**Problem**

There are situations where a SQL Server databases is handed over to you and you find that the primary data file is unnecessarily huge. Such large data files may present management difficulties such as the case where you cannot take partial backups or you are unable to migrate data files smoothly using the detach and attach method.

**Solution**

One key solution is to identify the largest tables in your primary file group and rebuild the table(s), directing the data to another file group which you have created with multiple data files possibly on separate disks.

but, I dont know .how can i split any schema on a separate data file(.mdf) in EF Core 5 (Code First)?

Comment: No, this is far beyond EF's league.

Comment: you mean that, i have to create database simple , and modify it on ssms ?